# Click at link by address template

Tags: html, dom, selenium, click

I'm using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for making some work: script should click at link followed by it's own address. For example, there is a method: clickAndWait. I have to pass it link title. But at my page this title changes, so I have to pass address to click at.

Could you help me with this?

p.s. I asked this question in selenium group, but still have no answer.

---

**upd:** For exampe, I have such html-code:

```
<a href="lalala.com">Some changeable title</a>
<a href="another.com">Some changeable title</a>
```

And selenium pseudocode:

```
ClickAndWait('Some changeable title')
```

But I have to click at site 'another.com', not 'lalala.com'. And link's title changes every time. Only link address is the same.

Comment: Please provide more information. A snippet of your HTML could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the following locators:

```
//use XPath to match links with full href value
selenium.clickAndWait("//a[@href='another.com']");

//use XPath to match links with href values that start with string
selenium.clickAndWait("//a[starts-with(@href,'another.com')]"); //use partial href value

//use XPath to match links with href values that contain string
selenium.clickAndWait("//a[contains(@href,'another.com')]"); //use partial href value
```

Comment: Check, please, your code. There should be second '[' -> ']' otherwise it won't work. For example:     ("//a[contains(@href,'another.com')]");

Comment: And another one small question: how can I click at second fount link? (I use your 3rd sample). I tried somethinkg like [2] at the end of the command, or /[2]. This won't work for me =) Thanks.

Comment: Try `//body/descendant::a[contains(@href,'another.com')][2]`

Comment: Thanks, have no more questions.